# SQL Timeout error

Tags: c#, sql

Getting this **error**:

```
NativeError = 258
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
SQLState = HYT00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 258
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response
```

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property to 0.
For more info, there is a MSDN article  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

Comment: This is a login problem, not a SQL query problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934751) useful. If your login problem meets the criteria listed in that article, then it's a known SQL Server 2005 bug and there are workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your SQL server or try increasing the pool size in your connection string.